# changing background image css using jquery to find unique src from foreachloop

Tags: jquery, css, laravel-blade

I have a foreach loop which displays data for a carousel. To make each image displayed unique i have added a id to each div inside the loop. Instead of using img tags i have used div to keep the image size consistent without skewing the image. Using jquery I am attempting to find the id of the div, finding the img inside the div and the unique src associated with this and then taking that src and adding it to the parent divs css as a background image. I am currently getting this variable (imgSrc) as undefined. How do i successfully change this css using jquery?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var imgId = $('.carosuelProperties').attr('id');
  var imgSrc = $(imgId).children('img').attr('src');
  console.log(imgSrc);
  $(imgId).css("background-image", "url(" + imgSrc + ")");
});

 @if (isset($participatingProperties) && !empty($participatingProperties) && is_array($participatingProperties))
    @foreach ($participatingProperties as $property)
    <a href="/view/property/{{ $property->property_slug or $property->id }}">  
      <div class="carousel__box itemProperties col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="propertyTitleCaro centered white sub-header">
            <?php echo mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($property->property_name), 0, 45, '...'); ?>   
        </h2>
        <p class="centered white smallerText propertyDesCaro"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($property->property_short_descript), 0, 140, '...<br><br>SEE MORE'); ?></p>
        <div class="carosuelProperties" id="{{ $property->id }}">
            <img class="caroImgClass" src="{{$property->property_main_image->images_main}}" alt="{{ $property->property_name or 'No name' }}" title="{{ $property->property_name or 'No name' }}">
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @endif
```

Comment: Side note: You should not place block type elements like `div` or `h2` inside an inline element like `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate thru each element of the carrousel, your code just changes the first slide and not all the slides.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Get all elements
    $('.carosuelProperties').each(function() {

        // Set the reference to the current element
        var current = $(this);

        // Find the image
        var image = current.find('img');

        // Set the background image
        current.css('background-image', 'url(' + image.attr('src') + ')');

    });

});
```

Comment: Bang! yes perfect. Thank you

Comment: have you tried doing  this with bootstraps carousel?

Comment: No, but if you post the code i can help you with that. @TheRealDude

Comment: awesome thanks dude. let me change my code and get back to you, should i start a new question for it?

Comment: Here is an example of a carousel using bootstrap. Similar layout I also have used a tryptic style. https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY

The problem i have is that only one div can be active. But when my code is in a loop I only need to assign the class active to the first 3 I believe.

Comment: And what you want to achieve? I didn't found the image code in you example. @TheRealDude

Comment: @TheRealDude which element needs the background image applied in this case?

Comment: I have created a snippet online with the appropriate code.. I really appropriate this man. https://jsfiddle.net/Lqeqtjb2/

Comment: @TheRealDude the question remains the same. You have repeated slides for each slide (with your code to clone the elements). What does the background image script must do? Assign the background image to each cloned element?

Comment: I think the problem here is i need to addclass active to the divs on display.. and using next/back to manipulate this class?

Comment: @TheRealDude the active class is assigned by the carousel script. I still don't get what you want to achieve. You need to do exactly what to the active divs?

Comment: in the loop i have added the class active to all items. This displays all of the items.. I need to use javascript to only add this class to the active divs.. In a static carousel this works naturally like the example i sent you earlier.. however with this dynamic data i will need to edit the javascript.

Comment: @TheRealDude where did you added the `active` class? The examples you provided don't have the `addClass('active')` or inline class anywhere.

Comment: active seems to be associated with the class item in both examples..: <div class="carousel__box itemProperties col-md-4 col-sm-12 item active">

Comment: @TheRealDude that's what i told you, the class `active` is set by the bootstrap carousel script. What i still don't get, is what you wanna do when a slide gets its active class. And i don't get why are you cloning those div. What is the purpose of that.

Comment: Bootstrap only displays active class. so without it, nothing displays. I need to add this class to the first 3 nth-child-of. Then using the next/back buttons change the class to the next cilds in sequence.

Comment: I have created a new question which is in coalition to this.. if u can help please do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393350/how-could-i-use-bootstraps-carousel-plugin-to-create-a-dynamic-carousel

Comment: i have another question if u can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466539/creating-a-crud-system-plus-and-minus-not-working-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a small mistake in your selector in line 3. Do it like this:

```
var imgSrc = $('#'+imgId).children('img').attr('src');
```

**EDIT**

You shouldn't even need javascript here.

```
@if (isset($participatingProperties) && !empty($participatingProperties) && is_array($participatingProperties))
@foreach ($participatingProperties as $property)
  <a href="/view/property/{{ $property->property_slug or $property->id }}">  
     <div class="carousel__box itemProperties col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="propertyTitleCaro centered white sub-header">
           <?php echo mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($property->property_name), 0, 45, '...'); ?>   
        </h2>
        <p class="centered white smallerText propertyDesCaro"><?php echo mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($property->property_short_descript), 0, 140, '...<br><br>SEE MORE'); ?></p>
        <div class="carosuelProperties" id="{{ $property->id }}" style="background-image: {{$property->property_main_image->images_main}};">
           <img class="caroImgClass" src="{{$property->property_main_image->images_main}}" alt="{{ $property->property_name or 'No name' }}" title="{{ $property->property_name or 'No name' }}">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

You could use the property of your image directly in a style attribute.

Comment: Awesome thanks, this works for the first div in the loop but not for the others?

Comment: Probably because your saving only the first object in a variable, not the following ones. I guess you need more dynamic variables like `var variable{{ $property->id }} = 'something'`

Comment: My bad, would you be able to help me set the background image for every div in the loop?

Comment: I am wondering if you even need to use javascript in this case. You could try to use the style attribute directly in your html code.

Comment: something like this: <div class="carosuelProperties" id="{{ $property->id }}" background="{{$property->property_main_image->images_main}}">

Comment: I updated the main answer ;) pretty simple if it works like this :D

Comment: has anyone tried doing  this with bootstraps carousel?