# creating a crud system, plus and minus not working javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am creating a CRUD system and I am having trouble adding and removing my data. The issue is the + (duplicate) works fine apart from once i - (minus) a column. How would i effectively write this code to add and remove columns flawlessly.

Hi I am creating a CRUD system and I am having trouble adding and removing my data. The issue is the + (duplicate) works fine apart from once i - (minus) a column. How would i effectively write this code to add and remove columns flawlessly.

```
                <div id="clone-container">
                    <div class="propertyNew row">
                        <div id="props">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Properties</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label>Current Price</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label>Price With Offer</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @if (!empty($offer->offerPropertiesPricing) && is_array($offer->offerPropertiesPricing))
                    @foreach ($offer->offerPropertiesPricing as $pricedPropertyId => $pricedProperty)
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control pComparrision" name="propertyListAssoc[]">
                                        @foreach($properties as $propertyListAssoc)
                                            <option value="{{ $propertyListAssoc->id }}" {{ $propertyListAssoc->id == $pricedPropertyId ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $propertyListAssoc->property_name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control price1" name="currentPrice[]" value="{{ $pricedProperty->current_price or '0.00'}}">
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control price2" name="priceWithOffer[]" value="{{ $pricedProperty->price_with_offer or '0.00'}}">
                                    </div>   
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <a id="deleteProperty" class="minus" onclick="minus()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus fa-1x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
                    <div id="propertyNew" class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="form-control pComparrision" id="pComparrision" name="propertyListAssoc[]">
                                    <option>No Properties</option>
                                    @foreach($properties as $propertyListAssoc)
                                        <option value="{{ $propertyListAssoc->id }}">{{ $propertyListAssoc->property_name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control price1" name="currentPrice[]" value="0.00">
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control price2" name="priceWithOffer[]" value="0.00">
                                </div>   
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <br>
                                <a id="deleteProperty" class="minus" onclick="minus()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-minus fa-1x"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a id="addExtraPropery"  onclick="duplicate()">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>
            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of x_panel -->
```

Comment: Pure javascript? Or you are using jQuery?

Comment: would prefer pure js, but whatever gets the job done. @muecas

Comment: Well, you are using a hybrid there, that's why i asked. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are removing the parent container of each cloned element, ant that parent contains all the cloned elements. Try this instead:

```js
// Clone count
var i =0;

// Cloned element cache
var copy = document.querySelector('.propertyNew').cloneNode(true);

// Container for the cloned elements
var container = document.getElementById('clone-container');

// Clone elements
function duplicate() {
    var clone = copy.cloneNode(true);
    container.appendChild(clone);
    i++;
}

// Remove the last element from the list
function minus() {
    // Keep at least one element
    if(i >= 1) {
        container.lastChild.remove();
        i--;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="clone-container">
    <div class="propertyNew row">
        <div id="props">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <label>Properties</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label>Current Price</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label>Price With Offer</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<a id="deleteProperty" class="minus" onclick="minus()">
    <i class="fa fa-minus fa-1x"></i> Remove
</a>

<a id="addExtraPropery"  onclick="duplicate()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i> Add
</a>
```

Comment: Hi i have edited the code above, this solution works but it just adds and removes the titles.. i have updated my code with the dynamic information.

Comment: @TheRealDude it stills has some pseudo code there. I need the plain HTML. I won't create that environment to reproduce that. :-)